# Bootstrap 3 - First <div> in a column breaks the layout if <p> is inserted into it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve a responsive layout in which there will be two rows, one column and three divs in that column.

**Example:**

```
ROW1: (DIV)(DIV)(DIV)
ROW2: (DIV)(DIV)(DIV)
```

In the first `(DIV)` there should be a text in `<p>` tags. Each of the latter `(DIV)s` have an image centered vertically and horizontally inside them.

**When there is no text in the first `(DIV)` then all `(DIV)s` work great.** The whole layout reacts perfectly to screen size change and there are no problems.

The problem is, **when there IS text in the first `(DIV)` then it is pushed down**, breaking the layout.

I have no idea why inserting any text in the first `(DIV)` causes those problems. Could anybody help me out with this?

**Examples:** (don't worry about missing images, it doesn't affect this problem)

[jsFiddle example (full-screen, here the layout is broken)](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8550/embedded/result/)

[jsFiddle example (non-fullscreen, emulating small screen size)](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8550/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For default the `vertical-align` for inline-block elements is `baseline`, when you add some text then the baseline reference is that text.

Try adding another value for vertical-align:

```
.logoRow > div > div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8553/)